# How is a dirty page mapped to a disk file flushed to the file in Linux?

Tags: file, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to figure out Linux IO internals.
In one application, I mmap a disk file to user space virtual address, the write some data to the virtual address. I think there triggered a page fault in Linux to create a PTE for the mapped disk file and the PTE has 'Dirty' bit set. After a while, something flushed the dirty page to disk file, thus writing to file through mmap is done.
So my question is what component in Linux kernel detects the 'Dirty' page to do the page flushing and how ofter does this detecting and flushing happen?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/sect-oracle_9i_and_10g_tuning_guide-memory_usage_and_page_cache-tuning_the_page_cache

Comment: Yeap, page cached is used to cached the file data. Then who flushes the dirty page to the disk file? How ofter is the dirty page flushed from cache to disk?

Comment: This is part of the 'knobs' on the page cache.  There is a time that a page is idle (not being written) and when the timeout happens, it will be backed by disk.  Or it can be evicted due to memory pressure.  See: https://www.evanjones.ca/linux-write-caching.html